# Salat on the trampoline?

Tags: salat

My teenage son had the idea to perform salat on the trampoline. It seems to me a funny idea but I found no reason why not. Are there any prescriptions apart from cleanness for the place to perform salat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location on which you may pray must primly fulfill one major condition: It must be tahir. If for example you use a prayer mat on a najasah that has dried or of a dry kind you are already safe at least from this perspective.

However it would hardly make sense to perform the prayer on a trampoline due to the fact that the vibrations may cause dizziness and this further could cause you to maybe invalidate your prayer. So it is recommended to pray on a solid ground if available.

**Some more details/maybe somewhat off-topic**

Also note that prayer on a (moving) mount is only regarded as permissible in case of voluntary prayers by the majority of scholars based on the [sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1000). However contemporary scholars regard it permissible to pray on air planes (by analogy) and ships (for this we have an evidence in the sunnah), but in case one could stop and pray on a solid ground (coast, airport) it is regarded as better also if possible the prayer should be performed in a regular manner meaning one should stand for the prayer.
Here's the quote from imam a-Shwakani's book Nayl al-Awtaar
نيل الأوطار of the hadith which was compiled by a-Daraqotni and al-Hakim from Nishapur in his al-Mustadrak who stated it was on the conditions of Muslim, his student al-Bayhaqi also reported it and considered it hassan and al-Albani considered it as sahih on the condition of imam Muslim:
 <sup>In the following I'm translating from Arabic language, as this translation is of my own take it carefully!</sup>

> عن ابن عمر قال : { سئل النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كيف أصلي في السفينة ؟ قال : صل فيها قائما ، إلا أن تخاف الغرق }
> On the authority of ibn 'Umar said: The messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him was asked, how can I pray in a ship? He replayed: pray standing, except if you fear to drown

All the above are examples of similar cases to that of a trampoline.
Also note in case of a congregation it is highly frowned upon for the imam to pray on a higher position compared to the rest of the congregation.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically it is fine, you could pray on the trampoline as it is not a soft surface and it is clean.

(although personally i wound see why you should even if it is permissible)

Comment: well, it actually is a very soft surface. Yes, and it's not my idea but teenagers sometimes have funny ideas and I am already glad that he wants to perform salat without papa saying you have to...

Comment: that's great sir. but i think it wouldn't be considered a soft surface technically since the ruling states that your face must not sink into the surface, so you can't pray on a bed for example.